# How to secure Angular2 cli app's access to Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am using Angular2 CLI with Firebase. The app is hosted on Firebase and it uses Firebase Realtime DB to store data. I have the firebase config as follows -

```
export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "[XYZ]",
  authDomain: "[ABC].firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://[ABC].firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "[123]"
};
```

Since the above config is in clear text and within the Angular2 bundle, it's visible to all. The users of the app do not authenticate with Firebase but the data generated and saved by them need to be secure so no one with just the app's apiKey, etc. can get to the data.  How would I go about ensuring that ONLY the users within my app can read/write data?

I've read the docs for Firebase Authentication, security and rules - and still unsure how to secure access to the database without either the App level or user level authentication.

EDIT - Further to Michael's response, here's my (I would think a non-unusual) scenario:

1. My App on a public URL hence open to all.
2. The users of the app do login using OAuth with one of many third parties. All of which return a unique token to identify the user.
3. I don't have control over how those tokens are generated.
4. I could pass those tokens to Firebase to uniquely identify users, but the data is not restricted to specific users. In other words many users have access to the same data.
5. How do I ensure that some hacker doesn't steal my app's Firebase access config and start reading/writing data?

Comment: People are free to explain their votes, or not to explain their votes, as they wish. We say that people may vote anonymously for any reason, as long as they don't focus on a single user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the configuration passed to `firebase.initializeApp()` is considered publicly disclosable. You **must not** rely on obfuscation to secure access to your Realtime Database. If you want to restrict access but you're not using one of the built-in providers of Firebase Auth, you should [generate a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) to identify your users.

Security Rules and Firebase Auth are the **only** ways to securely access data directly from a client.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Further to your answer, I've add EDIT 2 for more details. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: How are you getting the OAuth tokens? Through a server you run? Another third-party service? You will need some way to turn those OAuth tokens into valid Firebase custom tokens if you want to secure the data.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Currently the App is authenticating the user with a third party service using Oauth on Client side only. So the access-tockens are only present on the client side.  Seems like I'll have to add a server to the stack to handle Oauth and use the access-tokens to create firebase custom token.

Comment: Which creates an issue - since the app is also hosted by Firebase, which doesn't allow for Node server hosting. Seems like Firebase+AngularCli hosting doesn't support custom tokens, I guess. I'll have to open a ticket with them to figure this out.

Comment: You should look at [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) which *do* allow you to run Node.js code server-side. In particular, this [sample code for authenticating with LinkedIn](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/linkedin-auth) will probably be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Michael. This helped a lot! I'm working through the Cloud functions and how to use them for my specific needs. Appreciate all the pointers and helping me make progress. I'll mark the question answered. Best.